# Anchor tag not working properly. When I open the webpage it behaves like a simple text not as a link

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink, html5-canvas, anchor

**This link in the code is redirecting me to google instead it behaves as a plain text.**

`<a herf="https://www.google.com">Forgot Password</a>`

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        
        <title>Messages</title>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle1.css" type="text/css"> -->

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class = message id = neutral>This is a message.</div>
        <div class = message id = good>This is a good message.</div>
        <div class = message id = warning>This is a warning message.</div>
        <hr />
       /*This anchor tag is not working*/<br>
        <a herf = "https://www.google.com">Forgot Password?</a>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: there is a typo in the tag - `herf` instead of `href`

Comment: +1 ^
use and IDE like https://code.visualstudio.com/ with many plugins that will help you catch such typos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        
        <title>Messages</title>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle1.css" type="text/css"> -->

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class = message id = neutral>This is a message.</div>
        <div class = message id = good>This is a good message.</div>
        <div class = message id = warning>This is a warning message.</div>
        <hr />
       /*This anchor tag is not working*/<br>
        <a href = "https://www.google.com">Forgot Password?</a>
    </body>

</html>
```

Only change I made was modifying the `herf` to `href`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo.
Change `herf` to `href`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        
        <title>Messages</title>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle1.css" type="text/css"> -->

    </head>
    <body>

        <div class = message id = neutral>This is a message.</div>
        <div class = message id = good>This is a good message.</div>
        <div class = message id = warning>This is a warning message.</div>
        <hr />
       /*This anchor tag is not working*/<br>
        <a href = "https://www.google.com">Forgot Password?</a>
    </body>

</html>
```